# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in my JSF page

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

currently, I try to execute this js function in my xhtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeLayer(id, L, T, W, H, bgColor, visible, zIndex) {
                console.debug("inside");

                    var toto = new Array();
                    var res2 ="";

                    toto.push('<div id="container"> hello world </div>');
                    res2 = toto.join();
                    console.debug(res2);
                }
            }
    </script>
```

but in web console I see that: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, and this error corresponding at `toto.push('<div id="container"> hello world </div>');`

How I can to fix this error ?

Comment: `//<![CDATA[ ... //]]>`.

Comment: Yes,
I did like that  : `<h:outputScript> //<![CDATA[ ........//]]> </h:outputScript> `